# Tokenizer with lower case filter not working

Tags: solr, lucene

```
<fieldType name="keyword" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer> 
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>  
</fieldType>
```

Filed definition:

```
<field name="name" type="keyword" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I have a data where value for the above field is `APPLE-INC`

I expect this to be searched when I do `apple-inc`. It is not happening.

Any thoughts?

[image: Analysis]

Comment: how are you using the solr? are you using it in cloud mode? Did you checked the same on the solr analysis page by selecting the field?

Comment: It's a stand alone server which is running on windows machine.

Comment: access the solr analysis page and check how the data is getting indexed and query is happeing..after modifying the schema.xml ...did you restarted the server or reindexed the data?

Comment: Have you reindexed after changing the field? How are you searching against the field?

Comment: Thanks. I added the query value and index value. Index analysis looks like not converting to lower case. Why so?

Comment: @MatsLindh As I have indexed true and the field is indexed at the time of insertion.

Comment: You might have not restarted the server after the schema.xml changes...do restart the server and re-index the data

Comment: re-index data means...push the data again to the server after the schema modifications

Comment: No. It is a fresh data @AbhijitBashetti. because I deleted the data folder earlier and started the Solr server then added the data using post tool

Comment: could you please add the screenshot of the solr analysis page

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Please check the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211208/discussion-between-abhijit-bashetti-and-gibbs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the below field type in the schema file.

```
<fieldType name="keyword" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer> 
      <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/> 
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>  
   </fieldType>
```

Here is the output getting on the analysis page.
Please refer the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: My bad. As you said, it should be working. Though my schema file has lower case, it is not uploaded, I am checking into that.

Comment: I got that. I am using a directory where my config files are present. `solr.cmd create -c search -d`. This file is outdated. I understand that reindex means reinserting the data. Is it so?

Comment: yes...reindexing means re-inserting or pushing the data again ...so that new fresh index gets created adhering to the modified schema.xml

Comment: It is really costly operation when there is huge amount of data :( If data is dynamically generated, how can we reinsert that?

Comment: You shouldn't keep the data in Solr as your primary data storage if you expect to change or add types. You'll need to re-index in those cases, i.e. send the data again from outside sources. If all fields are stored you can in effect reindex it by making Solr re-submit it to itself, but I'm not sure if there's any built-in support for that yet (outside of making small atomic updates that doesn't affect any real fields).

Comment: @MatsLindh Now I got it why cassandra and all used as a storage. Thanks